# Are these two Objective-C message expressions equivalent memory-wise?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

Do the following two message expressions result in an increase of retain count in the same object?

Example 1:

```
iVar = [Foo aClassMethodInFoo];
[iVar retain];
```

Example 2:

```
iVar = [[Foo aClassMethodInFoo] retain];
```

Example 1 is explicit in that it's iVar instance whose retain count is increased. 
Example 2 seems to suggest that it's retain count of the object returned from `[Foo aClassMethodInFoo]` that is increased. If that is so, then assuming `aClassMethodInFoo` is a convenience method, which object do I 'release' to balance the earlier 'retain' in order not to leak memory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are absolutely identical. In the first case, you're assigning the results of a method call to a variable, then calling `-retain` on that variable. The net result is the variable holds the object, and you've called `-retain` on the object. In the second case, you're calling `-retain` on the results of a method call, and assigning the result of that to the variable. As `-retain` is guaranteed to return its receiver, the net result is the variable holds the object, and you've called `-retain` on the object.

In both cases, the memory semantics are precisely identical. According to the naming conventions defined in the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html), a method named `+aClassMethodInFoo` returns an autoreleased object, so your call to `-retain` is correct if you're storing the results in an ivar. As such, when you're done you can call `-release` on your ivar. Your question of "which object do I 'release'" is nonsensical because there's only one object here.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the class method returns a new object rather than void, they are exactly equivalent because retain just returns self.

Comment: Yes, the class (convenience) method is assumed to return a new object.

Comment: Even if it didn't return a new object, they'd still be the same.